# Visual Studio for Mac connecting to VSTS Projects

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-mac

I am having some difficulties trying to get Visual Studio for Mac to connect to my VSTS projects through my Visual Studio monthly plan.

I have followed this guide:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control

I got the extension, but what I am not seeing are the projects listed.  I am able to see the projects on Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.  For the Mac version, I am just seeing VSTS, 3 Projects.  None of my projects are showing up.  Even if I complete the guide, I am not seeing any of my projects in the Mac version.

Am I doing something wrong, or does Microsoft just not support their own services?

Thanks!

Comment: <Quote>Team Foundation Version Control support is currently in preview and some functionality is not yet fully working. We'd love feedback from you on any issues at Developer Community. More changes are still to come! </Quote> ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover Well that makes sense then haha!  I ended up just getting the new Git client for macOS - Tower.  It is able to pull my repositories

Answer (score 0):

The guide you refer to is for using Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) with Visual Studio for Mac, not Git. I suppose the 3 projects you can see are using TFVC version control.